# Batch process pdfs to do a Flesch-Kincaid readability test

Tags: batch-file, flesch-kincaid

I have about 1800 PDF files that I have to extract Flesch-Kincaid grade level scores from. Does anyone have any ideas as to how I should best approach this? I need a score per PDF.

Comment: How is the score presented in the PDF files?  Is it in an image, plain text ??

Comment: Oh I meant that, I have to run a program or the algorithm itself on the PDFS to get the scores. The PDFs are just content from which a score has to be generated. There is a program Flesh.exe that gives a score on a document, but it can only do it one at a time.

Comment: and what makes the flesh with the score?

Comment: I'm not sure what you mean by that, but the score I need is the Grade Level score, which is calculated by the following: (0.39 × Average Sentence Length) + (11.8 × Average Syllables per Word)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If flesh.exe takes a filename and outputs the results to stdout then this should run it on every PDF file.

```
@echo off
for %%a in (*.pdf) do (
flesh.exe "%%a"  >> file.log
)
```

Comment: Makes sense, but when I run it, it just runs the program without doing anything and keeps opening it if I close it. Sorry, I'm not exactly experienced in this! Everything is in the same folder.

Comment: Check if there is a file.log in the folder.  What is inside it?  How do you launch FLESH.EXE and where does it show the result?

Comment: It's there but there's nothing in it.

Comment: Okay so when you launch Flesh.exe, to open the PDF you can either click on "Choose" and select the file in a small window, or you can drag the file into the program. Once a file is selected, you click "Process." The results are shown in a small box below the Process button (can't be highlighted or selected) and can be saved via File -> Save or Save As.

Comment: Then you need a tool like Autoit.  Batch files cannot manipulate a GUI like that (well SEND KEYS can in a VBS script).  Check to see if Flesh.exe has command line switches.  try typing flesh /?

Comment: Ah, I see. So within AutoIt I can set a script to have it navigate the GUI and batch process the PDFs?

Comment: Yes, it should work for that.  Does `FLESH /?` bring up any help or switches?

Comment: Am I supposed to type that into the command prompt? In that case, no it does not.

Comment: Yes, at a cmd prompt.  It's probably just a GUI tool in that case.

Comment: I see. Looks like I have to fiddle around with AutoIt then. Thank you for your help! I'd give you rep if I could.